# Mac, Windows, Linux - which platform for web development?

Tags: linux, windows, macos

I am using Windows at the moment and i am working on web development. However, my development approach is some kind of retro. My projects are old and i would like to switch to a responsive layout and OOP code on my PHP side. I did some research on new web design and development concepts.
Some examples are Foundtation and Bootstrap framework for responsive and clean HTML/CSS, Laravel and other PHP frameworks for my MVC needs.

However, it seems like all new concepts and frameworks are based on such servers/tools: sass, nodejs, grunt, ruby, mixture and so on... Even Google Web Fundamentals examples are just working on OS X enviroment.
All tools are compatible with Mac OS X mostly. I would like to build a fresh working enviroment.
My intention is not to start another controversy between Windows, Mac and Linux users.
Just wanted to know how to setup best enviroment for my web design and development purposes.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Anything that is not windows is preferred at best it is crippled and at worst it is useless

Linux is easier for those with less experience due to it being closer to what your deployed server will look like.

OS X is fine also but has a extra learning step or 2 for those who are less experienced when it comes to setup and config.

And OS X has support for all the fancy graphic design tools ( as well as excellent hardware support )

Comment: I have decided with Ubuntu, i am going to run this on a virtual machine for a test drive. Another confusing thing that "web design" and "web development" whole seperated topics in terms of both technical and logical. I am usually creating front and sub pages as HTML/CSS and then coding with PHP. Is this the best approach? Should i switch completely to MVC? Any ideas?

Comment: That's a completely seperate question and should probably be posted as a separate question . My personal opinion that learning basics will never hurt.